# Display Jenkins output into Slack

Tags: jenkins, github, slack

I'm trying to display open/stale branches onto slack to remind people to admin them accordingly.

Ive gotten Jenkins to get the information needed from Git via shell commands.

But how can one display this information in the Jenkins UI console to a Slack channel?

Any suggestions?

S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into `incoming webhooks`. Slack provides you a link and you can send a curl command to put the message into slack.

More information here: https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks

Comment: Thank you for the tip, it lead me use slack bots and api calls to make it work!